# Submitting app on App Store

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I had uploaded an app on app store with version 1.1.0.

It was accepted and is now on sale.

Now I have made small fixes and need to submit the app again.

Will I be able to submit the app on store, if I keep the same version.

Comment: Its better to change the version to 1.1.1

Comment: You need to change the version to 1.1.1. This will make the versions distinct between the upgrades. Build version wont be used for version comparison.

Comment: Is updated version something without which the app won't be accepted by app store ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build version is not the version that `app-store` uses. It's just for the purpose of developers to refer for themselves. Both values needs to be incremented for application to upload.

**Bundle version** is the important one and should be updated if you want to update your app in `app-store`. It will also be shown in `app-store`.

Comment: note: both the version no needs to incremented by the way for app to be uploaded. it is just that build version is not shown to users or in app store.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to change the version of the app before uploading to app store. First you need to create a new app with new version like 1.1.1 And the same version you have to update in your info.plist file in version field OR you can change it in the Summary section 1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Build Version - This is for the developers to track of the build

App-version - this is for the application version check - using which the user's get a notification about a new version of the application being available for download.

Ideally, I don't think there is any reason to upload a fresh build without changing the app-version. The latest updates to iTunes connect enforces incremented Build version.